# How to get cells with different cell classes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to get the text from the `textfield` i.e from KgCustomCell and KgRepsCustomCell. I need to fetch the data from the field, when i run the buttonClicked method.

I have tried to add to instance variables, which contains kg and reps, but the first time i click the button, it's empty. The second time it's okay. But how can i load the data in the most correct way?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let index = indexPath.row

    if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 {
        let exerciseName = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Exercise Name", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LoggedExerciseNameCell

        exerciseName.lblExerciseName.text = self.exercise?.name

        return exerciseName
    }

    if index == 0 && indexPath.section == 1 {
        let txtFieldKg = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Text KG", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! KgCustomCell

        return txtFieldKg
    }

    if index == 1 && indexPath.section == 1 {
        let txtFieldReps = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Text Reps", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! KgRepsCustomCell

        //kg = txtFieldReps.textReps.text

        return txtFieldReps
    }

    if index == 2 && indexPath.section == 1 {
        let btnLog = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Button Log", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ButtonLogWorkoutCustomCell

        btnLog.btnLogExercise.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddLogViewController.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

       // kg = txtFieldReps.textReps.text

        return btnLog
    }

    if indexPath.section == 2 {
        let loggedExerciseInformation = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Logged Exercise", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LoggedExerciseCustomCell

        return loggedExerciseInformation
    }

    let noCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Button Log", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    return noCell
}

func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    let button = sender as UIButton

    if let superview = button.superview {
        if (superview.superview as? ButtonLogWorkoutCustomCell) != nil {
            try! LogManagerDAO.sharedInstance.realm.write({
                exercise?.loggedKg = 4//Int(txtKG.text!)!
                exercise?.loggedReps = 4//Int(txtReps.text!)!
                log!.addExerciseToLog(exercise!)

                loadLoggedExercise()

                tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @dashandrest Do not add tags to titles. There's already the... *tag* section for that, and there's already "ios" in here. See [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303606/is-it-ok-to-systematically-edit-the-questions-titles-like-this).

Comment: @EricD: okay, sure here onwards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the text of that textField than you can use delegate method of UITextField like this, first declare two instance var for that 2 textField's value

```
var strKG: String = ""
var strReps: String = ""
```

Now set delegate with textField in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let index = indexPath.row

    if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 {
        let exerciseName = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Exercise Name", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LoggedExerciseNameCell

        exerciseName.lblExerciseName.text = self.exercise?.name

        return exerciseName
    }

    if index == 0 && indexPath.section == 1 {
        let txtFieldKg = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Text KG", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! KgCustomCell
        txtFieldReps.textField.tag = index
        txtFieldKg.textField.delegate = self
        return txtFieldKg
    }

    if index == 1 && indexPath.section == 1 {
        let txtFieldReps = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Text Reps", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! KgRepsCustomCell
        txtFieldReps.textField.tag = index
        txtFieldReps.textField.delegate = self
        return txtFieldReps
    }

    if index == 2 && indexPath.section == 1 {
        let btnLog = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Button Log", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ButtonLogWorkoutCustomCell

        btnLog.btnLogExercise.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddLogViewController.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        // kg = txtFieldReps.textReps.text

        return btnLog
    }

    if indexPath.section == 2 {
        let loggedExerciseInformation = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Logged Exercise", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LoggedExerciseCustomCell

        return loggedExerciseInformation
    }

    let noCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Button Log", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    return noCell
}
```

Now add delegate method of UITextField

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
     if(textField.tag == 0) {
         self.strKG = textField.text
     }
     else {
         self.strReps = textField.text
     }
}
```

Now just use this two string object in your button action method.

Comment: Have you try my solution?

Comment: Hi @Nirav.
When i try your solution i get the following error: Cannot assign value of type 'AddLogViewController' to type 'UITextFieldDelegate?'.

It comes up with the error at this line: txtFieldReps.textField.delegate = self

Comment: You need to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` for your `AddLogViewController` like this way `class AddLogViewController : UIViewController, UITextField {`

Comment: Aah ofc. When i press the button it only fetch the data from the first textfield, if i press it again i get both. What am i doing wrong? @Nirav

Comment: Have you added value to both the textField before pressing button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118551/discussion-between-jakob-and-nirav).

Comment: Thanks mate, Happy Coding :)